# How to check "Set Product as New" in magento2(EE)?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I want to check "Set Product as New" from **list.phtml** in magento2(EE)?

[image]

I have tring to below methods:

```
$_product->getData('is_new') //not working
$_product->getIsNew() //not working
```

Anybody have any solution for this issue.

Comment: try to get this way -> <?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');?> <?php echo $helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getIsNew(), 'isnew') ?>

Comment: @PareshaU not working

Comment: Have you figured out how is_new works for Enterprise?  Could you please explain?

Comment: Have you ever figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

"Set Product as New" in admin just creates a row in table "catalog_product_entity_datetime"
and attribute_code in eav_attribute table is "news_from_date" so from list it can be reached like

```
$_product->getNewsFromDate()
```

but it will return a value like "2021-08-10 15:21:26" as it is datetime.
When disabled it simply deletes the row in catalog_product_entity_datetime

Comment: Thanks, this helped me much.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the product available, you can use this logic to check if it is a new product:

```
/**
 * Check if the given product is new and return true if it is.
 *
 * Should the Magento logic change, look in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/NewProduct.php
 *
 * @param ProductInterface $product
 * @return boolean
 */
public function showNewLabel(ProductInterface $product): bool
{
    $newsFromDate = $product->getNewsFromDate();
    $newsToDate = $product->getNewsToDate();
    if (!$newsFromDate && !$newsToDate) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->timezone->isScopeDateInInterval(
        $product->getStore(),
        $newsFromDate,
        $newsToDate
    );
}
```

Comment: For enterprise edition, new from and new to date attributes are not showing.